# cheapest iPad necessary for running Swift Playgrounds application

Tags: ipad, swift

What's the oldest (read: cheapest) iPad I can purchase that will run the Swift Playgrounds app for learning the Swift programming language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/swift-playgrounds/id908519492?mt=8):

> Swift Playgrounds requires a 64-bit iPad with iOS 10 or later, including iPad mini 2 or later, iPad Air or later, or iPad Pro.